# Why choose a traditional frame over an aerodynamically streamlined frame?

Tags: road-bike, racing, aerodynamics

I'm not talking specifically about triathlon frames, just frames which have aerodynamically shaped tubes. As I understand it, both types of frame are legal for road-racing under UCI rules.

So, why would one choose a traditional frame with round or "squoval" tubes over an aero frame? For example, why would one choose to ride a [Cervélo R5](http://www.cervelo.com/en/bikes/r-series/road-bikes-r5.html) with (more) traditionally shaped tubes over a [Cervélo S5](http://www.cervelo.com/en/bikes/s-series/s5.html) which would seem to be more aerodynamically sound?

Does it boil down to personal preference, or are there specific conditions in which one out-performs the other?

Comment: Are you taking price into consideration? Most probably the streamlined one costs much more, doesn't it? (by the way, gorgeous bikes!)

Comment: No, they're roughly the same price.

Comment: Oh, in the interests of full disclosure, I test drove both (well, the next model down in each case, the R3 and S2) and chose the S2 because it came with a SRAM Red group set. Both felt fantastic and I'm having a hard time figuring out why a company would provide both bike series if there is any clear advantage to one or the other.

Comment: I strongly suspect that "streamlined" frames do not provide measurable improvement over standard round frames.  They exist mostly for looks.  And they likely weight a hair more and make it harder to add things like a strap-on water bottle holder.

Comment: @DanielRHicks not to mention if you have to replace those fancy seatposts...

Comment: @DanielRHicks - the aero bikes do provide a very measurable difference over "standard" frames.

Comment: @KenHiatt -- I have my doubts.  The turbulence from the front wheel destroys any "streamlining" advantage for the down tube, and the cyclist's legs would likely do the same for the seat tube.  There may be a slight advantage to the curved seat tube of the S5 above, the way it hugs the rear wheel, but that would be the major part of it.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - You may have doubts but the differences have been measured in wind tunnels (with rotating front wheel) and also in field tests. Whether the difference is large enough to matter is a legitimate question; but whether the frames "provide measurable improvement" is not.

Comment: @R.Chung -- OK, I should have said "significant" rather than "measurable".  I can't see how streamlined tubes would reduce the drag of bike and rider by even 1%, and that advantage would disappear under real-world conditions.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - we can (and probably should) move this to a discussion room if you wish but these advantages don't disappear. Here's [an example of a field test under real-world conditions](http://forum.slowtwitch.com/cgi-bin/gforum.cgi?post=1802183#1802183) that measured the difference between two frames that were already pretty aero. Subsequently the rider raced in a 40K TT and his actual time came within half a second per km of the predicted time.

Comment: Like I said, the wheel-hugging seat tube WOULD have an effect.  "Aero" shaped tubes, no.  And in this test there's a strong chance of a placebo effect -- in fact, in the first trial the rider averaged (roughly calculating) 96 watts, while in the second case he averaged 127.  You tend to go faster when you expend more energy.

Comment: First, how could "a placebo effect" alter the recorded speed and power? Second, the field test was consistent with wind tunnel measurements. How could a placebo effect affect the wind tunnel? Third, I already pointed out that it was an example comparison of two frames that were already considered aero -- I used this example because the difference was *smaller* than usual. We really should move this to a discussion room if you wish to continue.

Comment: @R.Chung That's what the placebo effect *is*. He's alleging that the cyclist subconsciously tried harder because he believed he was on a faster bicycle. The placebo effect could absolutely effect metrics like speed and power output.

Comment: @meagar: Exactly. But the metrics are *not* speed and power. The metrics are CdA and Crr. We're using a power and speed recorder to record the data in order to calculate CdA and Crr, which are *independent* of speed and power. In fact, it's the variance in speed and power that make CdA and Crr estimable. We could have done the estimation with a powered electric bicycle, varying the throttle and speed and still estimated CdA and Crr. Even if the rider had a prior belief it's the relationship between power and speed that matters -- and that is what is recorded.

Comment: Hey, don't jump all over me, I'm completely uninvested in your argument. All I know is I read "how could 'a placebo effect' alter the recorded speed and power?" which would seem to indicate two separate measurements which could easily be affected by false believe in a placebo. I only mentioned them as "the metrics" because *you* mentioned them as the metrics. If you're saying that the power was the same but the speed increased, that wouldn't seem to be as easily linked to a placebo effect.

Comment: Speed increased for the same power output. Power output decreased for the same speed. Power and speed were recorded electronically at one-second intervals. The electronic recording device was not influenced by the rider's beliefs, so claiming that the estimation of Crr and CdA was the result of a placebo effect is incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

Aero frames are generally slightly heavier than the standard frame you'd compare it to, though the difference might not even be enough for the average person to notice. Someone who regularly competes in time trials might want the increased speed on relatively flat ground, competitors will certainly notice the difference.

If you're not competing in time trials or triathlons and you don't have an extra couple thousand dollars burning a hole in your pocket, you would probably choose the standard, more compatible, traditional, and lighter frame that is going to perform perfectly well on your average terrain. If you frequently ride on hilly terrain, the added cost and weight of the aero frame isn't likely to be worth the trade off.

Answer (score 1):

It will probably depend on terrain, speed, and other aerodynamic (or lack thereof) factors whether one would even notice a difference between an "aero" frame or a "normal" frame.

If you're climbing lots of hills, riding in traffic, or otherwise not in a position where wind resistance is your chief enemy, I doubt you'd see a benefit from going aero.

If you live out in the farmlands and ride on fast, flat roads, or somewhere that has lots of wind, you may notice a difference, because wind/air resistance becomes a factor.

Comment: Plus it seems to me like you should optimize the wind resistance of your body before your frame.  Things like: wearing tight clothing, lowering your handlebars, using areobars, getting a more airo helmet seem like cheaper, easier alternatives that are not permanent investments.